# Google Play Console: API access page not found

Tags: android, google-play-console

When I go to my account settings, I do not see the "API Access" as expected. I think the page has been deleted by Google..

Any ideas how can I link cloud project to my Poogle play console account?
Until now, can't verify token purchase for in-app product.

[image: API Access not found]